# How to avoid connection errors in Android async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, timeout, httpclient, connection-timeout

In my android app I am calling a php script which outputs xml to use within the app. From analytics I found out that some users can't get the data because of the following errors:

```
libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)


java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /81.19.145.162 (port 80): connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)


libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)


libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)


java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /81.19.145.162 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

The Code for the async task looks like this:

```
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            fullUrl = new StringBuilder(url);
            fullUrl.append("&lat=" + String.valueOf(lat) + "&lng=" + String.valueOf(lng) + "&token=" + token + "&types=" + types + "&limit=" + limit);
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(fullUrl.toString());
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);

            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            xpp.setInput(reader);
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (xpp.getName().equals("GeocacheTypeId")) {
                        typeSet.add(xpp.nextText().toString());
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equals("Code")) {
                        gcSet.add(xpp.nextText().toString());
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equals("Name")) {
                        nameSet.add(xpp.nextText().toString());
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equals("Latitude")) {
                        latSet.add(xpp.nextText().toString());
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equals("Longitude")) {
                        lngSet.add(xpp.nextText().toString());
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equals("HasbeenFoundbyUser")) {
                        foundSet.add(xpp.nextText().toString());
                    }

                }
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showError(context.getResources().getString(R.string.xmlerror), false);
            sendToAnalytics();
        }
```

The called url looks like this:

```
http://mywebsite.at/folder/getcaches.php?getcaches&lat=37.9249409&lng=-92.5329998&token=%xxxx%2BVIMwAcVFvV0PCEQWCsb12I%3D&hidefounds=true&username=someuser&types=2%2C3%2C8%2C9%2C12%2C1304%2C3773%2C137%2C6%2C13%2C453%2C3653%2C3774%2C4738%2C4%2C1858%2C5%2C11%2C&limit=1
```

For me everything works perfectly and I can't reproduce the error. I think there are problems with different mobile providers in different countries.

I hope you can tell me, how I could avoid these errors.

Edit - Manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.package"
    android:versionCode="16"
    android:versionName="3.02" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="my.package.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="my.package.OAuth"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="myscheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

        <receiver
            android:name="my.package.WidgetProvider"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_provider" />
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="my.package.UpdateReceiver" />
        <receiver android:name="my.package.H24Receiver" />
        <receiver android:name="my.package.BootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="my.package.WidgetService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="mykey" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

> libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
>
> java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /81.19.145.162 (port 80): connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
>
> libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
>
> libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)

These are all connectivity problems at the user's end. There isn't really anything you can do except to tell the user to check network connectivity and try again.

> java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /81.19.145.162 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

This means that the server was reachable but there was nothing listening in the port i.e. the web server was down. Work to increase the reliability of your server. For the end user the message is that there are temporary problems and the user should try again later.

Comment: I don't think that these are "just" connectivity problems at the user because I got quiet a lot bad reviews because of the errors. From my analytics I see that there are 5-10% recieving errors.